# Trying to save my workbook as an xlsx on a few laptops

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to save a Macro (xlsm) workbook as an xlsx file using the FileDialog method. It works perfectly on my laptop, but it throws an error when used on some of my friend's computers. I've tried all possible solutions that I could find on the internet, but it is weird to me how the code does not work on only a few computers.

The error is

> Run time error 1004 - Method 'SaveAs' of object _workbook failed

```
Sub cleanTheSheet()
 
 Dim sh As Worksheet
 Dim book As Workbook
 Dim Fldr As String
 Dim fileName As String

 
 fileName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input").Range("B1")

'Please note - Worksheet "input" has the client name that is used as part of file name. The name is plain text without any special characters that could cause an issue. 

 Set book = ThisWorkbook
 
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 
 With Application.FileDialog(4)
     .AllowMultiSelect = False
     If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
     Fldr = .SelectedItems(1)
 End With
 
 book.Save

 book.SaveAs Fldr & "\" & fileName & "_Global Payroll Pricing_" & Format(Date, dd_mmm_yy) & ".xlsx", xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

Comment: How about using double quotes: `"dd_mmm_yy"`? And `& ".xlsx"` is redundant i.e. it is covered by `xlOpenXMLWorkbook`.

Comment: Are you using `Option Explicit`? Unless you have a variable called `dd_mmm_yy`, your format string is undefined and `format` will format the date according to the system settings - and if the user has a slash as date separator,  this will result in `17/12/2020`. And a slash is not a valid character in a file name.

Comment: @urdearboy - Yes they are all windows computers and they are saving them locally.

Comment: @VBasic2008 - Yup the .xlsx seems to be redundant, I've taken it out now.

Comment: @FunThomas - You nailed it! the "/" in the date format was the issue. My laptop uses a "-" between the dates whereas some computers use a "/". When I removed the date format, it works ok on all systems. 

Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I knew that I would get the answer as soon as I took it to stack overflow.

Comment: Redundant in this case means not necessary, but you can still leave it if you feel it makes the code more readable. The important issue is the double quotes around `dd_mm_yy`: it has to be `"dd_mm_yy"`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 - I understood the redundant part. Will I get the actual current date if I add double quotes to my date format?

Comment: An easy way to find out is to use this line in a sub: `Debug.Print Format(Date, "dd_mm_yy")`. I would prefer `Debug.Print Format(Date, "yyyymmdd")` though.